# Issue in getting a property in a JSON file using jQuery GET

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I ma using jQuery get to retrieve a simple property on a JSON file.
With the following script I get undefined.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        var urlOriginal = 'http://xxx.com/xxx/xxx/xxx/resources.js';
        var urlResource = 'proxy_dr3.php?proxy_url=' + encodeURIComponent(urlOriginal);
        $.get(urlResource, function(data) {
            console.log(data); // I can see all the content from the JSON FILE
            console.log(data.urlPage); // undefined - PROBLEM HERE
            var urlHTML = data.urlPage;

            /*$.get(urlHTML, function(data) {
                $('#result').html(data);
            });*/

        });


    });
</script>
```

content for resource.js is json

```
{

        "urlPage": "http://xxx.com/xxx/xxx/xxx/article_517d960f0cf2fe38916a2f9d.html"
    }
```

The result type in Network is `text/html`. After loading resource.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$.get` won't guess it's JSON as the mime type your server gives is wrong.

You could parse the provided value (which is probably a string) using `JSON.parse` but you should use `$.getJSON`, so that the callback receives a parsed value.

```
    $.getJSON(urlResource, function(data) {
        console.log(data); 
        console.log(data.urlPage);

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use any one method which is best suitable for your app.

```
$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            data: "ur data",
            url: "ur url",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function(data) {
            }
        });
```

or you can use $.getJSON function